# Gesture recognizer delegate: how to implement touch delegate functions

Tags: iphone, uiview, delegates, uigesturerecognizer

I'm actually trying to insert touch delegate functions (type `touchBegan:withEvent`, or `touchEnded:withEvent`) inside a customScrollView class that implement `gestureRecognizers`.

When I try to set the delegate of the recognizer object to self, my SDK has a message of warning stating "incompatible type id ".

I understand that the delegate protocol of GestureRecognizer does not include such function, but I don't know which delegate I should trigger in order to use the aforesaid function inside my custom view.

Thank you very much for your responses

Victor-Marie

Here is my code:

```
@interface TapScrollView : UIScrollView {

  //  id<TapScrollViewDelegate> delegate;
    NSMutableArray *classementBoutons;
    int n;
    int o;
//UIImageView *bouton;

}
//@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TapScrollViewDelegate> delegate;
//@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *bouton;

//@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPanGestureRecognizer *bouton01pan;

-(id)init;
-(void)initierScrollView;

-(void) createGestureRecognizers;
-(IBAction)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender;


@end



#import "TapScrollView.h"


@implementation TapScrollView

//@synthesize bouton;

- (void)setUpBoutonView {
    // Create the placard view -- its init method calculates its frame based on its image
    //boutonHome *aBoutonMain = [[boutonHome alloc] init];
    //self.boutonMain = aBoutonMain;
    //[boutonMain setCenter:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
    //[self addSubview:boutonMain];
}

- (id) init 
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        NSLog(@"Classe TapScrollView initiée");
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)initierScrollView
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
        UIImageView *bouton = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [bouton setTag:i];
        [bouton setFrame:CGRectMake(72+20*i,10,62,55)];
        [classementBoutons insertObject:bouton atIndex:i];
        bouton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
        recognizer.delegate = self; 
        [bouton addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        [self addSubview:bouton];
}
}
//- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
//{    
//  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
//[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

  //  for (o=1; o<6; o++) {
  // if ([touch view] ==  [self viewWithTag:o]) 
  // {
  //   UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:[classementBoutons objectAtIndex:o] action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
   // [[classementBoutons objectAtIndex:o] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
   // bouton01 = [self viewWithTag:o];
   // }
   // }

    //CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    //[self animateFirstTouchAtPoint:touchPoint];
  //  return;
//}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (n=0; n<6; n++) {
        NSLog(@"touche cancelled");
        [[classementBoutons objectAtIndex:n] setFrame:CGRectMake((72+20)*n,10,62,55)];
    }


}

//- (id<TapScrollViewDelegate>) delegate {
//   return (id<TapScrollViewDelegate>)super.delegate;
//}

//- (void) setDelegate:(id<TapScrollViewDelegate>) aDelegate 
//{
//    super.delegate = aDelegate;
//}

#define GROW_ANIMATION_DURATION_SECONDS 0.15
#define SHRINK_ANIMATION_DURATION_SECONDS 0.15



-(IBAction)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Mouvement ok");
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, 
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying:

```
@interface TapScrollView : UIScrollView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
```

In this way, your warning should disappear, although I have to admit I have not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish, so there might be other problems.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It worked although I did not found such functions in the Delegate protocol for gestureRecognizers (maybe it is a reference to its super class).

Comment: `touchesCancelled` and its family belong to `UIResponder`, so they are already defined for your scroll view derived class. you can override, them, of course, as you already do...